# Reinstantiating a GUI (JFrame) object

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

basically I want my JFrame to become a completely new JFrame object when an event is triggered. I have some code that basically calls `GUI gui = new GUI(x, y)`
the only problem I'm having is that as well as creating the new GUI object, it is not deleting the old window. Can anyone tell me how to get rid of the old window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to call [dispose](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) on the existing JFrame first to free it up immediately.